# Securty options in embeded linux?

Tags: linux, embedded, docker, lxc

I am working on an embedded Linux platform. In our platform there is only root user. Now we want to bring in security options like

```
1. Low Privileged user.
2. Allowing to run only executables from a particular location(only read permission).
3. Use Linux Containers
```

We have managed to add a low privileged user using the /etc/passwd file. But I have no idea how to do the rest. Is there any better options to implement security in the linux system. Any documentation or links are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Option two is achieved by the `noexec` flag on mounting. The slight challenge is figuring out exactly what to mount where; you'd want to mount `/` as `noexec` to get safety by default, but you need `/sbin/mount` to be executable. But you can probably make / read-only and mount all the writeable filesystems as noexec.

Comment: The above answer works for me. Is there any way i can impose an rule, like only binaries with specific set of names are only allowed to execute??

Comment: @Griffin: That wouldn't be too secure. The usual approach would be `chroot` to an environment with just the trusted executables. A more flexible approach would be SElinux policies.